# pass 3 dots argument to another function

Tags: c, function, c-preprocessor

I have function called `foo` and that function takes `...`, I want to pass all the argument that passed in `...` to the function called `oof`, sample code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


void oof(FILE * f, const char * fmt, ...){
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(f, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}

void foo(const char * fmt, ...){
    oof(stdout, fmt, ...); // how can I pass the 3 dots?
    // do other things in the function block
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    foo("Hello %s\n", "World");
}
```

I don't want to pass to `oof` a `va_list`, but the arguments themselves

Comment: You don't pass the three dots. They indicate a variable number of arguments within the function declaration.

Comment: It's almost impossible to pass the arguments themselves.  This is [question 15.12](http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: There's a way to do this if `foo` is a macro.

Comment: Why don't you want to pass a `va_list` to `oof`?  Given what you've posted, that would be the right way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `oof` to accept a `va_list` and pass that.

```
void oof(FILE * f, const char * fmt, va_list args){
    vfprintf(f, fmt, args);
}

void foo(const char * fmt, ...){
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    oof(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: Except that passing a `va_list` is what the OP said they didn't want to do...

Comment: @SteveSummit, that can be true, but... Do you know another way to do that?

Comment: @LuisColorado The only other way I know is a macro, as in tstanisl's answer.

Comment: ... Since you have vararg macros, which is not always.  The macro solving way will lead at some point you to have to use plain functions, and you will lead to the original problem.  And you don't only need the `__VA_ARGS__` macro, but also the `##` comma elimination artefact (which is a GNU extension, if my memory doesn't fail too much)

Comment: @LuisColorado I didn't say "The only other good way I know is a macro"!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a function but you can do this with a macro:

```
#define foo(...) oof(__VA_ARGS__)
```

There is still an issue.

Where do you get `FILE *f` argument from?
Assuming it is `stdout` then define the macro as:

```
#define foo(...) oof(stdout, __VA_ARGS__)
```

amd if you want to eliminate some parameters (doing the inverse of above, just do the following:

```
#define foo(a, b, ...) oof(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687119/dbush)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69365398/5264491) (**dbush** should get the credit - do not accept my answer over theirs), but slightly modified because of OP's statement:

> I don't want to pass to `oof` a `va_list`, but the arguments themselves

Because a `va_list` needs to be passed to something, I define a different function `voof` called by both `oof` and `foo`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void voof(FILE * f, const char * fmt, va_list args){

    vfprintf(f, fmt, args);
}

void oof(FILE * f, const char * fmt, ...){
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    voof(f, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}

void foo(const char * fmt, ...){
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    voof(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    foo("Hello %s\n", "World");
}
```

`foo` and `oof` currently do the same thing, apart from the extra `FILE *` parameter in `oof`.